# AWS Skill, enable a smart home skill with self OAuth 2.0 server

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I built an OAuth 2.0 server, and I had verify the implementation of the custom OAuth 2.0 server by [postman in chrome](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/introduction), and an nodejs oauth client. It works.

My question is, when I launch `Amazon Alexa app` in android, and enable the skill. The login UI disappears. It shows nothing. So, I cannot login to get back oauth accessToken.

I use Facebook OAuth service instead now, it works fine. But I still need the custom OAuth 2.0 server to be workable. I doubt it's self-signed SSL certification now, and I will check it in these days.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Self-signed` SSL certification, it doesn't work. With a `trusted` SSL certification, the login UI shows.

### Conclusion

After many tests, the custom OAuth 2.0 server for alexa service, must meet following conditions.

1. The ssl certificate **MUST** be signed with trusted organization.
2. The https port **MUST** be 443, not a custom port. (Ex: 12345)

In some android mobiles, a self-signed certificate or a custom port, the login UI will display. But they all failed at another step for `accessToken`. The step for `authorize` is not a problem, but step for `token` seems to be blocked by alexa app. I suppose alexa app will check the port number, and it doesn't trust self-signed certificate.